# AvroParquet slow on reading?

Tags: performance, avro, parquet

I've run some performance benchmark on 6Go of data stored in different formats: CSV+Gzip, ParquetAvro+Gzip and Parquet+Gzip. I ran a simple Pig script that just loads the data and write an empty output. The tests were run on the same machine in the same conditions. Here are the results:

- CSV+Gzip: 23 mins
- AvroParquet+Gzip: 35 mins
- Parquet+Gzip: 11 mins

I see some bad performance with AvroParquet, is that expected? Has anyone experienced the same kind of issue?

--------------------------------- UPDATE ---------------------------------

For the same blocks, the InternalParquetRecordReader takes much more time to read the records in memory. But still, it is only a fraction of job. Here is a sample of what I see in the logs:

Parquet:

```
Jul 17, 2015 7:08:49 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 163 ms. row count = 21493464
Jul 17, 2015 7:09:01 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 147 ms. row count = 19451260
Jul 17, 2015 7:09:10 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 97 ms. row count = 13314248
Jul 17, 2015 7:09:15 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 35 ms. row count = 46992661
Jul 17, 2015 7:09:34 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 78 ms. row count = 12035159
Jul 17, 2015 7:09:40 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 28 ms. row count = 17718888
Jul 17, 2015 7:09:49 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 45 ms. row count = 19528965
Jul 17, 2015 7:09:55 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 76 ms. row count = 55428025
```

VS AvroParquet:

```
Jul 17, 2015 6:31:26 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 2049 ms. row count = 21493464
Jul 17, 2015 6:31:58 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 1621 ms. row count = 19451260
Jul 17, 2015 6:32:28 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 1467 ms. row count = 13314248
Jul 17, 2015 6:32:45 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 666 ms. row count = 46992661
Jul 17, 2015 6:33:45 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 933 ms. row count = 12035159
Jul 17, 2015 6:34:03 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 963 ms. row count = 17718888
Jul 17, 2015 6:34:32 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 2242 ms. row count = 19528965
Jul 17, 2015 6:34:56 PM INFO: org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 507 ms. row count = 55428025
```